# Dataframes NAtype to binary Julia

Tags: dataframe, binaryfiles, julia

I'm trying to write binary text files from a data frame in Julia using something along the lines of:

```
for x in RICT["$i"]["Sick"]

    write(f9, convert(Int16, x ))
```

and everything works nicely except for when it comes to NA values. Missing values are treated as NA it seems, and I know that there are different ways of handling such values using the data frames package. Does anyone have any experience with these NAtypes? Should I convert the NAtypes to a more conventional type and then write them in? As always any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What's the Python connection?

Comment: What do you want to write for the ``NA`` values? Do you want to just ignore them?

Comment: I'd like them be a blank space or ignored.

Comment: Moreover, does anyone know where NAtype falls in the matrix of more conventional data types (Int64, Float32, ASCIIString, etc.)? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are writing a 16-byte integer value, there's no canonical representation of "blank", so you'd have to pick a special 16-byte integer value that represents NA. A common choice for this kind of thing is the smallest representable value – in this case `typemin(Int16) == -32768`. You can generalize this to other signed integer types.